# Where can I find a library for converting WMV to MP4?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Any suggestions where I can find a library for converting WMV files to MP4?

A free / open source utility would be okay, too. Although this would require manually converting the files through a GUI, it would work for our small project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualDub is an open-source converter that is used in numerous media-editing projects.  I'm not familiar with the API myself, but I understand it's relatively easy to work with (as easy as media editing/transcoding can be).  You can find it at:  http://www.virtualdub.org/

Some free tools you can use out-of-the-box:  
 - Any Video Converter:  http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/ - very easy to use for batch-conversion of many files
 - Handbrake:  Open-source, very powerful - http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php

You can find a ton of media-editing/transcoding info at doom9: http://www.doom9.org

HTH,
James

Comment: Handbrake did a great job. Thanks!